# Output string with leading spaces to log, keeping the spaces

Tags: sas

How can I print leading spaces to the log?

When I do something like

```
data _null_;
  x = '  Hello, world!';
  put x;
run;
```

The result is

```
2522  data _null_;
2523    x = '  Hello, world!';
2524    putlog x;
2525  run;

Hello, world!
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

I looked through the [PUT documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000161869.htm), but nothing stood out to me.  It seems like using a format, such as [$CHARw.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000205096.htm), might work.  However, that would require knowing the length of the string ahead of time.

I would like the log output to look like this:

```
  Hello, world!  (<--edited by hand to display leading spaces)
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+2` (or however long) works with put (but not putlog).

```
data _null_;
  x = '  Hello, world!';
  put +2 x $;
run;
```

With `putlog` you must [add an @ or something similar to trick the compiler](http://support.sas.com/kb/40/403.html):

```
data _null_;
  x = '  Hello, world!';
  putlog @ +2 x $;
run;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `@` is not printing anything nor is it a nonprintable character - it's a pointer control, but it avoids the compiler/parser thinking `putlog` is a variable named `putlog` instead of a statement/function [since `putlog+2` would be a legal SAS statement if it were).  (While `put` apparently gets priority as a statement/function, `putlog` doesn't get that level of preference.  Presumably because it is newer, so to avoid backwards compatibility issues.)

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem of outputting the leading space in the variable.

Comment: @Tom why do you say that?  It certainly seems to do so for me.

Comment: Or do you mean when it contains spaces in the variable itself . I suppose not but that didn't seem to be a significant factor given the question.

Comment: The `H` should be in column 5 since you skipped two spaces and the variable has two leading space, but it is in column 3 instead.

Answer (score 4):

So you can use @n pointer control if you just want to add leading spaces.

```
putlog @3 x ;
```

If you want to conditionally build X such that it only sometimes has leading spaces then you could use the `$varying.` format. You will need to define a variable with the length you want it to write, but you do not need to modify the format used.

```
166  data _null_;
167    do i=3 to 1 by -1 ;
168       x = substr('  Hello, world!',i);
169       len = length(x);
170       putlog x $varying80. len ;
171    end;
172  run;

Hello, world!
 Hello, world!
  Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a non printable character - works with both put and putlog

```
data _null_;
  x = '09'x !! '       Hello, world!';
  putlog x;
run;
```

Other ways of creating 'blanks' in your log include:

```
data _null_;   
  x = '09'x !! '       Hello, world!';   
  put // x // '09'x; 
run;
```

The `/` lets you add a blank line.

Also, you can class sections of your log as NOTE / WARNING / ERROR by adding a dash, as follows:

```
data _null_;
  put 'NOTE: ';
  put 'NOTE- Check';
  put 'NOTE- This';
  put 'NOTE- Out!';
  put 'NOTE- ';
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @Joe's answer and built from it.  It turns out that the `+` pointer control is dynamic.  That is, the pointer position can be controlled by a data set variable.  This is good for when you don't know how many spaces there will be.

```
211  data _null_;
212    string         = '       Hello, world!';
213    len_string     = length(string);
214    len_stripped   = length(strip(string));
215    leading_spaces = len_string - len_stripped;
216
217    put len_string= len_stripped= leading_spaces= ;
218    put;
219    put +leading_spaces string;
220  run;

len_string=20 len_stripped=13 leading_spaces=7

       Hello, world!
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```